# como faço um row_number mantendo o numero do documento com diferentes parcelas?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

gostaria de saber como crio um row_number mantendo os numeros de documentos iguais criando a sequencia pela parcela.
exemplo:

```
doc / cliente / parcela
10     15         1
10     15         2
10     15         3
23     59         1
23     59         2
23     59         3
```

meu sequencial tem que ficar apenas 1 e 2 pois são documentos de números iguais diferenciando apenas as parcelas. da maneira que estou fazendo aqui o row_number ta criando o sequencial a cada doc ficando 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 e dessa maneira não é o correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja se no meu exemplo abaixo atende a tua necessidade:

```
create table #temp (doc int,cliente int)

insert into #temp
values
 ('10','15')
,('10','15')
,('10','15')
,('23','59')
,('23','59')
,('23','59')

select *
    , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY doc ORDER BY doc ASC) as Parcela
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY doc) AS 'Row Number'
    , RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY doc ) AS 'Rank'
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY doc ) AS 'Dense Rank'
    , NTILE(4) OVER ( ORDER BY doc ) AS 'Quartile'
  from #temp
```

Resultado:

```
doc |cliente|Parcela |Row Number    |Rank   |Dense Rank |Quartile
10  |15     |1       |1             |1      |1          |1
10  |15     |2       |2             |1      |1          |1
10  |15     |3       |3             |1      |1          |1
23  |59     |1       |4             |4      |2          |2
23  |59     |2       |5             |4      |2          |2
23  |59     |3       |6             |4      |2          |2
```

Uma breve explicação sobre funções de Ranking:

```
ROW_NUMBER () OVER ([ <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>)
```

Retorna o número seqüencial de uma linha dentro de uma partição de um conjunto de resultados, começando em 1 para a primeira linha em cada partição.

```
RANK () OVER ([ <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>) ([RANK () OVER <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>)
```

Retorna (Rank) a posição de cada linha dentro da partição de um conjunto de resultados.

```
DENSE_RANK () OVER ([ <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>) ([DENSE_RANK () OVER <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>)
```

Retorna (Rank) a posição de linhas dentro da partição de um conjunto de resultados, sem quaisquer lacunas no ranking.

`NTILE (integer_expression) OVER ([ <partition_by_clause>] <order_by_clause>)`

Distribui as linhas de uma partição ordenada em um determinado número de grupos.

Comment: Uau! Desculpa pela demora a responder Ricardo. Uma ótima explicação.
Pode ter certeza que irei anotar tudo aqui, pois sei que vou precisar disso futuramente. Bem detalhado e bem explicado. Brigadão mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez assim dê certo então:

```
WITH DocumentoLinha AS
(
     SELECT RC1_DOCREC, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RC1_DOCREC) AS NumeroLinha
       FROM RECEBER1 
   GROUP BY RC1_DOCREC
)
SELECT R2.RC2_DOCREC,
       R1.RC1_CLIENTE, 
       R2.RC2_PARCELA,
       DL.NumeroLinha
--INTO MIG_DOCREC
  FROM MIG_CARAJAS.. RECEBER1 AS R1 INNER JOIN
       MIG_CARAJAS.. RECEBER2 AS R2 ON R1.RC1_DOCREC = R2.RC2_DOCREC INNER JOIN
       DocumentoLinha AS DL ON R1.RC1_DOCREC = DL.RC1_DOCREC
 WHERE RC2_DOCREC IN ('12-G','50-G')
```

Comment: talvez eu não me expressei bem, mas eu falei após o exemplo que dei. 

dessa forma ai eu também fiz e não deu certo.

dessa forma o numero do documento se repete, eu não quero que eles se repitam, o numero dos docs devem ser iguais... vc fez o exemplo criando o sequencial das PARCELAS. eu quero criar o sequencial dos documentos, mas se mantendo iguais quando os documentos também forem iguais.

Comment: Poste um preview da tabela original e uma do resultado final por favor, para ver se o q estou pensando aqui agora é o que realmente quer.

Comment: publiquei um novo comentário, pois não consegui formatar o script por aqui

Comment: editei a resposta, vê se agora deu certo.

Comment: deu certinho Weiner. Vc é fera mano. Muito obg.

aproveitando a deixa kk, vc sabe me dizer pq a sequencia do row_number fica tão esquisita? ele gerou assim 1, 55, 104, 166, 235, etc.

Answer (score 0):

o meu select:

```
SELECT RC2_DOCREC,
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY R2.RC2_DOCREC ORDER BY R2.RC2_DOCREC) NUMDOCUMENTO,
RC1_CLIENTE , RC2_PARCELA
 --INTO MIG_DOCREC
 FROM MIG_CARAJAS.. RECEBER1 R1
INNER JOIN MIG_CARAJAS.. RECEBER2 R2 ON R1.RC1_DOCREC=R2.RC2_DOCREC
WHERE RC2_DOCREC IN ('12-G','50-G')
```

o que retornou:
obs: row_number é a segunda coluna

```
12-G            1   12  1
12-G            2   12  2
12-G            3   12  3
50-G            1   12  1
50-G            2   12  2
50-G            3   12  3
50-G            4   12  4
50-G            5   12  5
50-G            6   12  6
50-G            7   12  7
50-G            8   12  8
50-G            9   12  9
50-G            10  12  10
```

As parcelas da tabela do cliente já estão formatadas corretamente. Eu quero criar um sequencial dos documentos. Desta forma que vc me passou ele está criando um sequencial como de parcelas.
O resultado que eu quero que ele traga é apenas o documento 1 e 2 para os documentos 12-G E 50-G